# Auto versioning for dacpac file while build

Tags: version, auto, dacpac

I have a requirement to auto version dacpac file name. I found this link
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0c93a55-d8bd-4a32-89d9-f46013fc1235/automatic-version-increment-on-datatier-applications?forum=ssdt
It helped, but can we change  to something like sequence 1.1, 1.2 instead of calculating based on days & seconds?

can we change  to something like sequence 1.1, 1.2 instead of calculating based on days & seconds?